# Custom view in recyclerview set width and height

Tags: android, view, android-recyclerview, android-canvas

I have a custom view as element in my recyclerview but it takes more spaces as need broken the alignment if the left text views has different lenght.

**MyCustomClass**

```
[...]
public MyCustomClass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    setupPaint();
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
   int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
   int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
   this.setMeasuredDimension(parentHeight, parentHeight);
   super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}

private void setupPaint() {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(faceRadius,faceRadius);
    setLayoutParams(params);
    //paint setup
}
[...]
```

**LIST LINE XML FILE**

```
[...]
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_one"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <view
            android:id="@+id/layout_two"
            class="example.android.cv.MyCustomView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
[...]
```

Now I obtain this, but i want to reduce the width to get a "square custom view" around the smiley face.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried without the call to super in onMeasure?

Comment: It seems to work deleting super class call, thank you!